# link (trunk )2 home switch together

Tags: switch

Can  i link two home switch (not professional like cisco) togeher in this way:

router 1 -> switch 1 -> switch 2
router 1 -> switch 2 -> switch 1

I want that when switch 1 goes down i still have switch 2 working

I also wants that the connections between the devices connected to the switch 1 and switch 2 are made through switches and not trough router.

It is possible?

http://postimg.org/image/o842cv3xj/

Answer (score 3):

Your question is bordering on incomprehensible, but the short answer is **no**. On an unmanaged switch, you will create a loop which will render your network inoperable in a very short space of time.

Comment: watch at this pics http://postimg.org/image/o842cv3xj/

Comment: @user2119955 Yeah, you're not going to be able to achieve what you want to achieve using consumer hardware.

Comment: It's not inherent to unmanaged switches, the relevant part is support for "Spanning Tree Protocol" (STP) which is very rarely seen on unmanaged switches